# Variable in jquery

Tags: javascript

How can I use this property `.animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');` here :

```
forcedScrollToTop = () => {
    let ul = this.scrollarea;
    ul.scrollTop(0);
};
```

I want to call jQuery’s animate here instead of the native scrollTop method?

Comment: Very unclear what you are trying to ask. The question title is very bad, please go read [ask] in that regard. And what you actually want or what your problem is, is also not clear. Do you just want to call jQuery’s animate here instead of the native scrollTop method? Well then wrap `ul` in `$()` to get a jQuery object (right now it seems to be a DOM element reference), and call the method …

Comment: @misorude Yes I want to call jQuery’s animate here instead of the native scrollTop method?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("#btn").on('click', function() { 
   $("HTML, BODY").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000); 
});
```

Comment: What is `btn` here?

Comment: html/css ID of  a element   button for example :
<button id="btn">Scroll</button>